# defineing unique constraint in play framework 2

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0

i have a user model which has an Id managed by the framework but also an email attribute
i want the email to be unique and at the moment im doing it using

```
@Email
@Required
@Column(unique=true)
public String email;
```

this works fine but its throwing an PersistenceException.
Does the play framework has a validation for this to be handeled at the form level.
I want to avoid try catch blocks around my user.save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same IDENTICAL problem. I ended up by using a method to check if that email already existed and then, if so, adding an error to the form.
Something like this:

```
Form<EntityClass> yourForm = Form.form(EntityClass.class).bindFromRequest();
if (EntityClass.mailAlreadylExist(yourForm.data.get("email"))){
List<ValidationError> validationErrorList = new ArrayList<>();
validationErrorList.add(new ValidationError("" , "email already used"  ,new ArrayList<>()));
yourForm.errors().put("", validationErrorList);
}
if (yourForm.hasErrors(){
return badRequest(yourView.render(yourForm));
} else {
//Do your stuff here, no PersistenceException will be thrown due to duplicate email
}
```

Worked for me, hope it helps

Comment: Select count(*)  from usertable where email = mail_i_want_to_check 
return count > 0 ? true : false;

Answer (score 1):

Unique contraints only refer to database: if they were defined at form level, form validation ("surface check") would need to query database to validate your object.

I believe that the exception is the best (or less bad) solution you can find.

To avoid many try / catch blocks, you may have a single entry point for "save" that do the job.